# A complex differential theorem applying to compact projective manifolds but not all compact Kahler manifolds

Tags: cv.complex-variables, soft-question, big-list

The following question may be soft, but I hope it is precise enough. The Hodge conjecture, if proven, would be a theorem in complex differential geometry that holds for all compact projective manifolds but for not all compact Kahler manifolds.

Is there any currently known complex differential geometry theorems of this nature, holding for all compact projective manifolds but not all compact Kahler manifolds?

Comment: What about :  every projective manifold contains a Riemann surface, but some Kähler manifold do not.

Comment: Made CW on request from the OP.

Comment: There's the nearly tautological observation that any compact projective manifold admits a line bundle with a positively curved Hermitian metric, but general compact Kahler manifolds don't.

Comment: Thomas' statement is in line with what I am looking for. Is there an analytic criterion for a Kahler manifold to contain a Riemann surface?

Comment: The  zero section of a positive line bundle would be a codimension one hypersurface of the ambient projective manifold. In this sense, Thomas statement is the dimension one case and Gunnar's statement is the codimension one case.